# Как хранить лайки в базе, вместе или раздельно?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Имею ввиду, если есть посты c лайками, комментарии с лайками, и допустим еще фотографии, то как их хранить - в одной таблице или раздельно?

Например, одну общую таблицу с полем какой тип контента залайкали

```
id --- type ------ id_content ---- who_liked  
1 ---- post ----------100--------------123  
2 ---- post ----------101--------------254  
3 ---- post ----------102--------------254  
4 ---- photo ---------100--------------123  
5 ---- comment -------100--------------123
```

Или сделать разные таблицы?
post_likes,
photo_likes,
comment_likes

Comment: Можно и одной таблицей.

Comment: *есть посты c лайками, комментарии с лайками, и допустим еще фотографии* ... и есть желающий лайкать определённый объект два раза в секунду...

Answer (score 2):

### Идея не совсем такая

Вам не нужно указывать тип, Вам нужно создавать связь Foreign Key с записью к которой собственно и относится.

Создавать нужно **именно** одну таблицу. Это рекомендуется по тому что это более расширяемый вариант, Вам не нужно удалять или создавать новые таблицы если появится необходимость в новых объектах которые можно пометить лайком.

### Что не так с Foreign Key?

Все прекрасно до тех пор пока мы не понимаем что есть небольшая проблема. Foreign Key может ссылаться только на одну таблицу, как же нам быть если таблицы разные?

Создаем вторую таблицу в которой храним

- PK ID
- Имя таблицы к которой прикреплены лайки

То есть в итоге у нас получится таблица

```
id  Name
1   Photo
2   Post
```

и теперь нам нужно только хранить Foreign Key на нужную запись из **этой** таблицы.

А затем умелое использование SQL поможет нам, подставлять значения из этой таблицы в наш SQL запрос.
То есть первым запросом мы получаем значение Foreign Key, и допустим оно равно `Post`.
Затем подставляем это значения во второй SQL запрос в котором ищем уже по этой таблице id, который хранился в нашей первой таблице с лайками.

В данном случае плюс Foreign Key не в целостности данных, по тому что здесь мы ее как раз совсем и не добьемся, а в простоте и расширяемости реализации.

**И да вам нужно будет всегда следить за тем что бы при удалении объекта, также и удалялись лайки.**

Comment: Тут есть одна проблема, что бы foreign работал все объекты должны быть одной сущностью. Если комментарии еще боле менее похожи на посты, то фотографии сюда притащить будет сложно ...

Comment: Мне вот единственное только интересно - вот кто имел дело с лайками - как оно? когда, например, сущностей порядка 100к - сколько примерно записей в таблице лайков получается? Запросы быстро отрабатывают - или почти сразу приходится еще заводить таблицу с суммами лайков по сущностям?

Comment: @Mike, да действительно сейчас напишем большую стать как с этим быть)

Comment: @Mike, а зачем им вообще этот Foreign Key oO? только для того чтобы лайки сами собой удалялись, если удаляется сущность? где-нибудь можно почитать про пользу Foreign Key? К сожалению, сам ни разу его не применял нигде = (

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Я бы скорее всего сразу делал кеш, на страницу выводится скажем 20 постов и по каждому считать лайки, это слишком дорого. С foreign дело не в удалении, его основное назначение обеспечивать целостность данных. Когда их нет, то многие мелкие ошибки в приложении остаются не замеченными и в итоге в данных начинаются не стыковки. например висящие в воздухе лайки, ни к чему не относящиеся. С лайками это полбеды,  могут быть случаи с гораздо более тяжелыми последствиями. В общем с ними правило одно, foreign _должен быть всегда_. Кроме крайне экзотических случаев